# Error with the Linq command -There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

the below linq statement :

```
    List<Column> columns = table.Columns.Cast<Column>().SelectMany(t => table.Columns.Cast<Column>().Where(col => col.DataType.Equals(DataType.NVarChar(4000))).Select(col => col)).ToList();
```

is taking about 5 seconds to execute , and for 500+ tables , that is very long time. SO I decided to go for parallel loop. SO that process doesn't wait for the stament to get completed and procedds to next iteration. But getting the error -***There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first***

Below is my code -

```
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                        worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                        worker.DoWork += (_, args) =>
                            {
                                int count = 1;
                                foreach (Table table in DestinationTables)
                                {
                                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                                        {
                                            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                                                {
                                                    List<Column> columns = table.Columns.Cast<Column>().SelectMany(t => table.Columns.Cast<Column>().Where(col => col.DataType.Equals(DataType.NVarChar(4000))).Select(col => col)).ToList();
                                                    if (columns.Count > 0)
                                                        encryptedcolumns.Add(table.ToString(), columns);
                                                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
                                                        {
                                                            worker.ReportProgress(count++);
                                                        });


                                                }));
                                            thread.Start();
                                        }).Wait();

                                }

                            };
                        worker.ProgressChanged += (_, args) =>
                            {
                                ProgressBarCurrentValue = args.ProgressPercentage;
                                NotificationText[1] = "Configuration In Progress. " + Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(progressBarCurrentValue * 100/progressBarMaximumValue) , 2) + "% Completed";
                            };
                        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, args) =>
                            {
                                NotificationText[1] = "Execution Started. Please wait";
                                NotifyPropertyChanged("NotificationText");
                                ExecuteWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
                                NotifyPropertyChanged("ExecuteWorker");
                            };
                        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

If I add parallel foreach and remove all the three threads(backgroundworker ,taskfactory and innermost Thread) , then the system freezes and I am not geting updates at every iteration.

Comment: If the answer I gave has solved the problem please mark it as answer. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do parallel queries on a single ADO.NET connection, not with the common providers at least. Even with Entity Framework (which provides async functions since version 6), you'd need to create several contexts (each with its own connection) to do parallel querying.

[This link](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2014/04/01/async-processing.aspx) applies to Entity Framework, but I believe it's the same for any ADO.Net DataReader. Quoting:

> But … EF doesn't support processing multiple requests through the same DbContext object. If your second asynchronous request on the same DbContext instance starts before the first request finishes (and that's the whole point), you'll get an error message that your request is processing against an open DataReader.

That said, if the queries do not need information from each other, nothing prevents you from opening a different connection and querying in parallel, just not with the same.

Take into account that, in the most common cases, for simple queries like this, most of the time is spent on actually transferring the result data (and not on the query itself), and in that case, I don't think parallel processing would help (unless there's some kind of network cap that limits the data transfer rate per client port, or something like that)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description. Can you please let me know if there is an alternate way to perform the given linq operation within short span of time , as I am not sure why it takes time to compare datatype of each column of a table, since the connection has already been made and table details are already fetched to the list.

Comment: With the given details, and without seeing your database, I have no clue. I'm assuming (by your object names) that you are using Linq-To-DataSet, and I don't know how it performs. If it's possible you might want to check the resulting SQL and profile it... I know it's possible with Linq-To-Entities by checking the returned `IQueryable`, but I have never used Linq-To-DataSet so I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer . In my case this works  -

```
string sqlcommand = "SELECT s.name + '.' + ts.name AS TableName, 
c.name AS column_name, 
t.name + '(' + Convert(varchar ,c.max_length/2) + ')' AS Datatypename,     
c.PRECISION, c.scale FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.types AS t ON c.user_type_id=t.user_type_id 
INNER JOIN sys.tables ts ON ts.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = ts.schema_id 
ORDER BY s.name + '.' + ts.name, c.column_id";

DataSet dtset = DestinationDB.ExecuteWithResults(sqlcommand);
```

Here I am able to get the column types for all table within the dataset in one second(as compared to an hour :D) , which I can use to compare the column types

Comment: It's ok to answer your own questions in Stack Overflow, however, in its current state, this does not provide an answer to the question at all (since the question is about a precise exception that ocurrs when doing parallel operations on a DataReader). You should either edit your question to indicate that you don't need an answer (maybe providing this post), or make the actual question about the performance problem. I'm glad you found a solution :-)